# How to use StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource in Delphi XE3

Tags: sandbox, firemonkey

In a sandboxed app for MAC OS X, I need to use the NSURL function

StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource

But it not implemented in Delphi XE3, in the Macapi.Foundation.pas unit.

How can I add this to Delphi functionaity, so I can use it?

This function is neccessary, if you have a security-scoped bookmark and want to use the resoruce.

Thanks in advance, I know it is not a easy question.

Comment: 8 years later.. I expect you worked this out, since it's in your book! Sadly, the methods have *still* not been added to NSURL in Macapi.Foundation or iOSapi.Foundation